# Is there is any way to scroll to a position in list view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

in Instagram tap on a grid item will navigate to the particular indexed item in listview is it possible in flutter for similar photo apps

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

After click on grid item and navigate to other list page just pass index there,

```
itemScrollController.scrollTo( 
index: 150,
 duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
 curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
```